# my 8GB HP pendrive doesnot show up when i run fdisk -l but displays in disk utility...unable to format from ther or Gparted

Tags: partitioning

when i go to disk utility and try to format it shows input / output error while reading /dev/sdc

in Gparted it displays as unallocated space.

and in terminal when i run sudo fdisk -l it does not show at all.

what to do??

Answer (score 0):

Create a new partition table using gparted, then create a new partition on it and *then* format it!

If that *still* doesn't work, the drive is broken and needs to be replaced...  :-(

Comment: tried doing that ...it shows input/output error while reading /dev/sdc ..and then nothing happens...

Comment: i ran sudo badblocks -nv /dev/sdc to find bad blocks..the result was 
Pass completed, 7864320 bad blocks found. (7864320/0/0 errors)
Then tried sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1024 count=7864320

it results in 

dd: error writing ‘/dev/sdc’: Input/output error
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.00526822 s, 0.0 kB/s

Comment: Your drive is hosed...  And as you're a reputation 1 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as both of our reputations will go up!  ;-)